# Non-deprecated equivalent of <form target="...">

Tags: html, dom, xhtml, forms

I want to achieve the same as...

```
window.open('lalala.php', 'lalala', '...');
```

But I want to send a HTTP POST request instead of a HTTP GET request. Thus, I'm using the following:

```
$('<form/>').attr('action', 'lalala.php')
            .attr('target', 'lalala')      // w3schools.org says this is deprecated
            .attr('method', 'post')
            .append(hiddenParam('param1', param1))
            .append(hiddenParam('param2', param2))
            .submit().remove();

// hiddenParam is a function I created that returns an input tag
// the type attribute set to hidden,
// the id attribute set to the first parameter,
// and the value attribute set to the second parameter
```

However, the `target` attribute is deprecated. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do by non-deprecated means?

Comment: Don't always believe w3schools

Comment: *Never* believe w3schools until you've seen supporting evidence from a source that is actually trustworthy.

Comment: So, which is a reliable source? (And, btw, could the W3C sue this w3schools guys?)

Comment: The W3C is reliable, and I think they would have sued by now if they could. (I hear W3C asked W3s nicely to make it clear that they weren't related to the W3C and W3S said 'no').

Comment: For reference (as I came here from Google in search of an answer) _"The target attribute on the a element was deprecated in a previous version of HTML, but is no longer deprecated, as it useful in Web applications, particularly in combination with the iframe element."_ [http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html)

Comment: W3Schools === misinformation. More info: [W3Fools](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: @tatlar: Heh, thank God I don't do Web development anymore!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `target` is only missing in strict doctypes. It is not deprecated. The simplest solution is to use a transitional doctype.
2. All browsers that I am aware of do the right thing, even if you use a strict doctype.
3. If you must use a strict doctype, and you care that much about validation, then you can extend the doctype definition:

Just be aware of [this 'bug' in just about every browser](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2005/02/custom_dtds_int_1.html). The solution is to serve your XHTML as `application/xhtml+xml`, but this will cause IE to blow up, so you need to sniff for that browser before determining the content type. It's essentially one giant hack for a tiny check box on a validation form. It's usually a lot simpler to just use a transitional doctype.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" [ <!ATTLIST form target CDATA #IMPLIED> ]>
```

Comment: `target` is not deprecated anywhere. It just doesn't appear in strict doctypes.

Comment: What does `[ <!ATTLIST form target CDATA #IMPLIED> ]` do?

Comment: @Eduardo in theory, it tells your browser that there's an extra attribute on the `<form>` element called target. In practise, it causes your browser to throw up (unless you happen to be using Opera).

Comment: @Eduardo It's standard DTD language. If you actually go check out the XHTML DTD at `http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd` you'll see all sort of similar looking statements.

Comment: @Matthew: No way I'm going to go through all of this, but thanks anyway! (I don't know why fairies don't write a standards-compliant browser that runs on every operating system...)

Comment: @Eduardo Just use a transitional doctype and you'll be fine for validation. Or just ignore that one warning. As for the fairies, they have much more important things to do, such as picking up teeth from all the kids all over the world to sit down and write an elaborate piece of software that has to follow constantly moving specs. I honestly don't envy anyone any side of the HTML standard.

Comment: The Transitional doctypes are deprecated themselves (see note in the DTD file — "[…] should be avoided whenever possible").

Answer (score 6):

Use `target` — it isn't deprecated.

Comment: These guys say it is: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_target.asp . But they use ASP, so they can't be serious, right?

Comment: They are wrong (as usual: http://w3fools.com/ ) I challenge you to find a D in the Deprecated column for the target attribute at http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/attributes.html or a reference in any other official specification.

Comment: Thanks. Even though it makes me feel stupid to acknowledge I learnt everything I know about Web development from w3schools.org.

Comment: In XHTML 1.0 Strict and XHTML 1.1 the `target` attribute doesn't exist: validator.w3.org: 'there is no attribute "target"'. In Transitional or non-xhtml it's not deprecated.

Comment: @Floern — "doesn't exist" and "deprecated" are two different things. There isn't a 1:1 correlation between them.

Comment: @David Dorward: I know. The target attribute is not/was never deprecated. Either it does exist or it doesn't. ;)

Comment: I'm surprised to see that 7 years later w3schools still says this, I thought they we're supposed to of cleaned that site up....

Comment: @Liam — they improved things from being "Sheer horror" to "Pretty rubbish". Still best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<form target="lalala" ...></form>
```

Comment: That will target a new, unnamed, window and not the one opened with specific arguments.