# Terms and Conditions popup for website

Tags: javascript, html, popup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function myPopup(){
 window.open("http://supportplans.co.uk/wp-content/themes/MyProduct/TandC.html", 
            "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 300, resizable = 0" )
 return false;
}
//-->
</script>
<form method="post" target="_blank">
```

I have a PayPal button on my site and when clicked it opens a small window with the terms and conditions:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="RULSZYMU6S3KN" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="4MUG5X5JBXNCA" /
    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="I accept" />
```

When clicking I Accept, it opens the payment page on PayPal in the tiny window.

How do I get it to open the PayPal in a new window? I would also like the small Terms and Conditions window to close in the onClick method.

Comment: target="_blank" in the form tag :)

Comment: @AlecSmart Unbelievably, [W3Schools is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4828740/851811) when saying that the `form target` attribute is [deprecated](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_form_target.asp) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `target="_blank"` in the `<form>` in the terms and conditions page, and add an `onclick` event handler on the `<submit>` button that does `window.close()`.

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
        method="post" 
        target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="RULSZYMU6S3KN" />
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="4MUG5X5JBXNCA" />
    <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="I accept" onclick="window.close();" />
</form>
```

`window.close()` should work in the terms and conditions page, because it was also opened through javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Since the form will be submitted after you click the Accept button, you can redirect the URL to the payment page in your server-side code.

So the small Terms and Conditions window will not closed, but redirect to the payment page (still in the small window).

According to your comment, you can try to add below to the end of your server side code:

```
response.write("<script type='text/javascript'>");
response.write("window.close();");
response.write("window.opener.open(.....payment url....)");
response.write("</script>");
```

It will close the small window and open a new window for the payment page.

Comment: That's what it does already, I want it to either maximum the window when clicked as it goes to the payment page or close the small window and open a new one

Comment: It's just a plain HMTL page, there's no server side code. I need to pass parameters from the form and the window.opener won't do that